# How to hide the text in the picture using the least significant bit?

Tags: windows, steganography

How to hide the text in the picture using the least significant bit ?

Comment: Just guessing here, but I think you may just have to provide a tiny bit more information.

Comment: How how how not to ask a question. Here are some hints: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Stretch this bit (it should be elastic enough), and wrap your text vertically in the top-bottom direction

Comment: You've got to give us more information and context if you want to get good answers. There are tags other than "windows" for a reason. Voting to close until this is edited.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're not sure what you're asking. Perhaps go and research the general idea of [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't.
Slightly longer answer: it's a very inefficient form of steganography, it won't work for JPEG images, and for GIF/PNG it'll basically make your image uncompressable.

If you need stega for anything else but curiosity or school assignments, research existing offerings.

Comment: please can you help me in book to learn the advanced java or c#

Answer (score 1):

The technique you're thinking of is called Steganography. Here's a good post which explains the technique.  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/27950-steganography/

Comment: please can you help me in book to learn the advanced java or c#

Comment: Probably http://www.amazon.com/C-Depth-Second-Jon-Skeet/dp/1935182471/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1291603295&sr=8-2